# ajaxControlToolkit MaskedEditExtender bug?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm newbie with the ajaxToolkit.

I need to use a prefix and display the mask as "(5__) ___ __ __" even the control isn't focused.

It works fine except when it gets focus every time, it adds another "5" at the begining of the text.

So it becomes "(55_) ___ __ __" on second focus.

And becomes "(555) ___ __ __" on 3rd focus.

And becomes "(555) 5__ __ __" on 4th focus and so on...

Is there a bug or am I just doing something wrong?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="mobilenumber"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender runat="server" ID="mobilenumberex" TargetControlID="mobilenumber" Mask="(599) 999 99 99" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" MaskType="None" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a bug, but it is fixed in the latest version of Ajax Control Toolkit.
Try to [update your project](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Upgrade%20your%20project%20to%20AjaxControlToolkit%20v15.1&referringTitle=Documentation) to the latest version of ACT.

Comment: I am already using the latest (15.1.4) version and it still happens.

Comment: Well, maybe used the latest [source code](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) to check it. Did you try to download source code and check MaskedEdit behavior with it?

Comment: Thanks for help but no, I decided to completely remove the ajaxControlToolkit and used a javascript library instead. I couldn't trust that since a simple function was mulfunctioning. I'm enough with the 3rd party bugs.